# How To Check For 4 In Row In A Multidimensional Array (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, rubymine

```
double_array = [
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
]
```

Let's say the digits in this array change like so:

```
double_array = [
      ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["0", "1", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["0", "0", "1", "0", "0"],
      ["0", "0", "0", "1", "0"],
      ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
    ]
```

How would I get be able to detect on that with some kind of if statement? 
Something like if there are four in a row diagonally do [insert action here].

The same goes for if it were vertically or horizontally like so:

```
double_array = [
      ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
      ["0", "1", "1", "1", "1"],
    ]
```

I'd prefer the least complex way possible.

Comment: Show us what have you tried, are you stuck at some point ?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "has the same value up to certain point".

Comment: Like if I want to check the values of double_array[3] (the fourth one down) from 0 to 3, for example. Or if I want to check index 0 for each array inside the double array.

Comment: What do you mean by same values up to certain point? `double_array[3]` denotes fourth row, so do you want all values in fourth row? Question is not quite clear. Please provide more example as to what you're expecting, also add some code that you tried.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the fourth row, but I was also referring to the first four indexes in that row.

Comment: I'll try this one more time and honestly I really don't appreciate how this ended up being changed into something other than what I was actually asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_row_ndx = double_array.size-1
  #=> 4
last_col_ndx = double_array.first.size-1
  #=> 4

(0..last_row_ndx).each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |i,h|
  (0..last_col_ndx).each do |j|
    v = double_array[i][j]
    h[v] << [[i-1,j], [i,j]] if i > 0 && v == double_array[i-1][j]
    h[v] << [[i,j-1], [i,j]] if j > 0 && v == double_array[i][j-1]
  end
end
  #=> {"1"=>[[[0, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[1, 0], [2, 0]], 
  #          [[2, 0], [3, 0]], [[3, 0], [3, 1]], [[2, 2], [3, 2]],
  #          [[3, 1], [3, 2]], [[3, 2], [3, 3]]], 
  #    "4"=>[[[0, 3], [1, 3]], [[1, 3], [2, 3]]],
  #    "0"=>[[[0, 4], [1, 4]], [[1, 4], [2, 4]], [[2, 4], [3, 4]],
  #          [[4, 0], [4, 1]], [[4, 1], [4, 2]], [[4, 2], [4, 3]],
  #          [[3, 4], [4, 4]], [[4, 3], [4, 4]]]}
```